# Django partial template responses

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Is it considered correct/ are there any pitfalls in returning partial templates to ajax POST requests?

For example:

```
if request.is_ajax:
    # response is just the form 
    return render(request, 'contact/fields.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: by partial do you mean it's just some HTML? without a doctype or <html> tags?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Something like <div> a bunch of html </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most typical approach is returning JSON and then contructing whatever HTML you need client-side from the JSON data. However, it could be argued that this is mixing presentation with behavior and it would be better to clearly separate out the HTML.

On the flip-side, returning a block of HTML is about as polar-south of "RESTful" as you can get. In pure REST philosophy, the views should return data in a standard and reusable container (such as JSON or XML). Later if you needed to pull the form into an iOS/Android/WP7/etc. app environment rather than a webpage, the JSON/XML will serve you just as well, whereas the HTML is virtually useless.

I can easily see both arguments, and I don't think one is necessarily more right than the other. Ultimately, I think you just have to do what works best for your app and what "feels right" to you. Think in terms of what is more maintainable and extensible for your particular circumstances.

Comment: +1 for laying out the flip-side, but with Django 1.4 it should become commonplace to write client-side tests and this should definitely be handled by returning JSON data in a generic and RESTful manner.

Answer (score 1):

I have no yet tried this with form POST request but very similarly we return partial HTML to AJAX GET request to do page changes without loading the whole page. I think it would work well for form request as well (we are in fact debating at the moment whether to use this approach on a page with multiple different forms).

I think if done right it is not a bad design pattern. We accomplish this by changing which base template is extended based on whether it was an AJAX call.

A simplified example:

```
### view
base_template = "base.html"
if request.is_ajax():
    base_template = "base-ajax.html"
return render_to_response(request, 'page.html', {'base_template': base_template})

### page.html
{% extends base_template %}
{% block main %}new page content{% endblock %}

### base.html
<html>
<!-- complete html page -->
...    
{% block main %}this is what changes per page{% endblock %}
...
</html>

### base-ajax.html
{% block main %}this is what changes per page{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most of my ajax return responses return DOM elements and not the entire form.

(an example)

```
...
person = ''' <a href="/person/{0}" class="normalMenu">{1} {2}</a>'''.format(p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name)
q = simplejson.dumps({"person":person})
return HttpResponse(q, mimetype="application/json")
```

The above sends back a simple DOM element to the template and inserts it into a table at the bottom. Sliding in right to left.

If you send back the entire template, the entire screen will flash and won't get any slick animations. That is my understanding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for a couple of jQuery Dialogs. The dialog contents are requested by a AJAX request, the contents are rendered on server side and then returned and displayed. So far I have experienced no problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience i can say that there is no pitfalls. I just not very good design pattern (not good practice). I used to do that on pretty high loaded project.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the year 2023 (question was asked in 2012..). Django still doesn't support rendering a template without invoking the whole chain of template inheritance.

So here's a basic way of rendering partial template:

```py
from django.template import Context, loader

def render_template_to_string(template_name, context=None):
    template = loader.get_template(template_name).template
    context_instance = Context(context or {})

    with context_instance.bind_template(template):
        return template.nodelist.render(context_instance)
```

And your (partial) template can be as simple as:

```html
<ul>my partial list
{% for opt in options %}
  <li>{{ opt }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You then invoke it by e.g.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

resp = render_template_to_string(
        "path/to/partial/html", {"options": range(10)}
    )
return HttpResponse(resp)
```

FYI you might want to add support for some node exclusions, error handling, or better flexibility of what gets passed to `render_template_to_string`.