# how to implement live page reload with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-channels

i am new to ajax. i created function where you can submit form without reloading the page. and it worked perfectly.but i want to extend it more further in my django ajax app, when i submit the form the template where the form details are stored should also be updated live.
when i submit form and to see the post i need to reload the post page. i want to remove that..

**basically when i submit form my other templace should update that template live so i don't have to update it**

**add_post.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <form id="post_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>name:</p>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
        <p>email:</p>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
        <p>bio:</p>
        <input type="text" id="bio" name="bio"><br>


        <input type="submit">

    </form>



    <script>
        $(document).on('submit','#post_form',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'create/',
                data:{
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    bio: $('#bio').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                    
                },
                success:function(){

                }
            });
        });





    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    email = request.POST['email']
    bio = request.POST['bio']
    new_profile =post(name=name,email=email,bio=bio)
    new_profile.save()
    success = 'user'+name+'created successfully'
    return HttpResponse(success)
```

**listview is temporary just for testing**

```
class posts(ListView):
  model = post
  template_name = 'ajax_app/posts.html'
```

**postpage.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
 scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     {% for x in object_list %}
    <ul>
         <li>{{x.name}}</li>
         <li>{{x.email}}</li>
         <li>{{x.bio}}</li>
    

    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

pls give me a solution how i can live update my page data on form submit

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `basically when i submit form my other templace should update that template live so i don't have to update it`

Comment: You are posting to `url:'create/',` what does that page look like?

Comment: if I get it correct, you render the template at server side, you cannot "update" it with ajax.

Comment: see this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978879/django-partial-template-responses

Comment: see this link : http://doconix.github.io/django-mako-plus/topics_partial_templates.html